# Insert null at the end of the row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

How it is possible to insert null in the end of the row using `select` statement

For example, suppose:

```
select value from (select value state from datatable where dataname like 'BENCH_DATA_S_%'')state
```

and it will result four rows of one column

```
RECH
MACHINE
BOOKS
ETC
```

Now I want to insert null also at the end of the row.

I want this output:

```
RECH
MACHINE
BOOKS
ETC
null
```

I tried it by using `UNION` but it seems it is not working

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that your query returns 1 row with 4 columns of data?  That's not what you appear to be showing but it seems to comport with the "end of the row" comment.  Are you trying to add a NULL as the fifth row?  Or as the fifth column?

Answer (score 2):

If you want null to be *the last record* you may try something like this:

```
  select data 
    from (select value as data,
                 1 as sort
            from datatable
           where dataname like 'BENCH_DATA_S_%''

           union all 

          select null,
                 2
            from dual)
order by sort
```

I've added an extra column (sorted) for (possible) *preserving data column's (data) order*;
if order of data column doesn't mean anything for you, you can simplify the query:

```
  select value as data
    from datatable
   where dataname like 'BENCH_DATA_S_%''

   union all 

  select null
    from dual

order by data asc nulls last -- or data desc nulls last
```

Comment: Thanks!! can we do it without adding extra column?

Comment: @Java_Alert: I've added "sort" column just to preserve "data" order; if you ready to sort on "data" you can simplify the query - see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Try this too,

```
SELECT value FROM(
     SELECT value FROM datatable WHERE dataname LIKE 'BENCH_DATA_S_%'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT NULL value FROM DUAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a column:

```
SELECT RECH,
       MACHINE,
       BOOKS,
       ETC,
       null AS "null"
FROM   datatable
WHERE  dataname LIKE 'BENCH_DATA_S_%';
```

If you want to add a row:

```
SELECT RECH,
       MACHINE,
       BOOKS,
       ETC
FROM   datatable
WHERE  dataname LIKE 'BENCH_DATA_S_%'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   DUAL
ORDER BY
       RECH NULLS LAST,
       MACHINE NULLS LAST,
       BOOKS NULLS LAST,
       ETC NULLS LAST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Union should work. Just make sure to match the quantity of columns with the quantity of NULLs.

```
SELECT 1,2,3 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM dual
ORDER BY 1 NULLS LAST;
```